# Firebase: Getting new token after current FCM token expires

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a reactJS website with firebase as a backend. One of the main service that I give to my user is notification everyday. I had implemented a code to ask for permission, if they grant access, store them to my database. But after sometime I noticed that tokens are expiring. I did a research about it and found out about onTokenRefresh() method. I implemented that also. But I believe for some reason, it is not working correctly. I am not getting the new tokens if tokens are expired. I'll paste the snippet below of what I am trying to do.

On the main page,

```
if (!("Notification" in window)) {
      //alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
    }

    // Check whether notification permissions have already been granted
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
      // Refresh logic here
      this.checkForRefreshToken();
    }

    // Otherwise, ask the user for permission
    else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
      //Ask user here, then call another function for storing token
      this.addNewToken()
    }
```

If user is accepting notification for the first time, I call addNewToken() method

```
addNewToken = () => {

    this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {

      const messaging = firebase.messaging();
      messaging
        .requestPermission()
        .then(() => {
          return messaging.getToken();
        })
        .then(token => {

          firebase.database().ref('tokens').once('value')
            .then(snapshots => {
              let tokenExist = false
              snapshots.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                // console.log("Child snapshot: ", childSnapshot.key);
                if (childSnapshot.val().token === token) {
                  tokenExist = true
                  return console.log('Device already registered.');
                }
              })
              if (!tokenExist) {
                //  console.log('Device subscribed successfully');
                return firebase.database().ref('tokens').push(token);
              }
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.code === "messaging/permission-blocked") {
            // console.log("Please Unblock Notification Request Manually");
          } else {
            // console.log("Error Occurred", error);
          }
        });

     })

  }
```

Now if user has already subscribed, I am checking if onTokenRefresh() is called, basically if token needs a refresh.

```
checkForRefreshToken = () => {
      this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
        const messaging = firebase.messaging();
        messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
          messaging.getToken().then((refreshedToken) => {
            const token = refreshedToken;
            firebase.database().ref('tokens').once('value')
            .then(snapshots => {
              let tokenExist = false
              snapshots.forEach(childSnapshot => {

                if (childSnapshot.val().token === token) {

                  tokenExist = true
                  return console.log('Device already registered.');
                }

              })

              if (!tokenExist) {
                return firebase.database().ref('device_ids').push(token);
              }
            })

          })
        })

      })  
    }
```

I don't know what is going wrong here, but I am not able to get the new tokens.

For testing purpose, I have my own device with expired token, I deployed this code and opened my website on the device, refreshed the page etc but I didn't get the new token.

Also, it would be great if anyone can help me how I can test expired tokens locally.
I found different methods for an app, but not for website (javascript).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`auth.onAuthStateChanged(...)` will add an event listener to events signalling changes in the authentication state. In your code above, you expect that the code for `addNewToken` and `checkForRefreshToken` are evaluated immediately, but instead they are simply adding new event listeners. The same applies for `onTokenRefresh()`.

So reworking `addNewToken()` into an on-demand function yields:

```js
requestMessagingToken = () => {
    let authUser = this.auth.currentUser;

    if (!authUser) {
      console.log("Not logged in!");
      return Promise.resolve(false); // silently ignore & fail
    }

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    return messaging
        .requestPermission()
        .then((permission) => {
            if (permission !== 'granted') {
              throw 'insufficient permissions'; // notification permission was denied/ignored
            }

            return messaging.getToken();
        })
        .then(token => saveMessagingTokenForUser(authUser.uid, token))
        .catch(error => {
            if (error && error.code === "messaging/permission-blocked") {
                // console.log("Please Unblock Notification Request Manually");
            } else {
                // console.log("Error Occurred", error);
            }
            return false; // silently fail
        });
};
```

This has the added benefit of being able to handle auth state changes easily using:

```js
this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(requestMessagingToken);
```

Once you've been granted permission to send notifications, you can activate the refreshed token listener using:

```js
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
    let authUser = this.auth.currentUser;

    if (!authUser) {
        console.log("Not logged in!");
        return; // ignore
    }

    messaging.getToken().then((refreshedToken) => {
        return saveMessagingTokenForUser(authUser.uid, refreshedToken);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Unable to retrieve/store messaging token ', err);
    });
});
```

Lastly, to save the token to the database, instead of searching through your database for a matching device token as the value of a push ID, you can use the token itself as the key. Furthermore, to make outdated token management easier, it is best to split your tokens by user.

```
"userData": {
  "userId1": {
    "tokens": {
      "deviceToken1": true,
      "deviceToken2": true,
      "deviceToken3": true,
    },
    ...
  },
  "userId2": {
    "tokens": {
      "deviceToken4": true,
      "deviceToken5": true
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Using this structure, you can use transactions to check if the data has been stored in the database and use cloud functions to check for invalid tokens.

```js
saveMessagingTokenForUser = (uid, token) => {
    return firebase.database().ref('userData/' + uid + '/tokens/' + token)
        .transaction((currentData) => {
            if (currentData != null) {
                console.log('Device already registered.');
                return; // abort transaction, no changes needed
            } else {
                console.log('Saving token to database.');
                return true;
            }
        })
        .then(() => true); // no errors = success
};
```

On the server you could run a Cloud Function listening to new device tokens added to the database and check that user's other device tokens for expiry.

```js
exports.checkUserForOutdatedTokens = functions.database.ref('/userData/{userId}/tokens/{tokenId}')
    .onCreate((newTokenSnapshot, context) => {

    return newTokenSnapshot.ref.once('value')
        .then((tokensSnapshot) => {
            let tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

            const message = {
                data: {heartbeat: true},
                tokens: tokens,
            }

            return admin.messaging().sendMulticast(message)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.failureCount > 0) {
                        const dataToDelete = {};
                        response.responses.forEach((resp, idx) => {
                            if (!resp.success) {
                                dataToDelete[tokens[idx]] = null;
                            }
                        });
                        console.log('List of tokens that caused failures: ' + Object.keys(dataToDelete));

                        return tokensSnapshot.ref.update(dataToDelete); // deletes failed tokens
                    }
                });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I have some doubts here.
1. If you ignore my logic of implementation, how can I implement a onTokenRefresh() in best way possible. I mean, in a way that it acts like a event listener it is supposed to.
2. For onTokenRefresh() to trigger, user should at least visit our website once. What if user's token is expired and he has not visited my website for a long time, how will it trigger that listner?

Comment: 1) The code below "activate the refreshed token listener" is a listener and updates the token on refreshes. "alerted->get->set" is the simplest way to handle these events. 2) Token refresh events won't be fired unless the SDK has found an existing token to refresh and will fire a refresh event if the token changes. If for example, the user has cleared their browsing data, the SDK will not be aware it previously held a token and you should prompt your user for notification permission like you did the first time manually (the listener will not be triggered in this case).